# Feedback on Short Film Sound

Tags: shortfilm, feedback, design, adr

Yikes, didn't know how nervous I would be putting my work out to such a great group of professionals, but here we go:

[WAIT](http://vimeo.com/12307052) is a short film I wrote and produced last year.  In addition, as a challenge to myself, I did a full rebuild of the sound including all ADR, foley, and SFX.

Please let me know what you think - any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

more cloth and foley would make the adr feel more realistic. The ADR is too clean and very dead, need to add some life to it, subtle reverb/reflections. I like the music.

Answer (score 1):

Very good film, great idea.

Few of my points, the footsteps on the steps at the girls front door sounded very boxy probably just a little bit of reverb could help it. Also maybe add a few footsteps when the girl is leaving emphasising the snow at 6.15 onwards.

I really felt I needed the sound of the girl breathing around 1.14, it would really enhance the scene.

ADR for me could have had a bit of reverb when the girl is talking to the driver outside of the bus but liked the environment for inside. A lot of the lines were out of sync which put me off but the quality of recording is very good.

When the first bus pulls away from the stop it changes gear 3 times before it has moved away from the shot (is that normal?) and it fades away too soon.

The music to the track is spot on its great. Hope this helps, nice work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  

The ADR sessions gave me fits - I didn't realize it took a lot of skill and practice on an actor's part to give a good performance.  

The bus - of all the starting from a stop samples I had, it seemed to shift quickly.  I have driven a few trucks that are similar and 1st gear goes to about 4 miles per hour, 2nd to 10, and 3rd after that, so I didn't feel it was unreasonable.